# Rails: weird behaviour in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud, form-for

I have a namespaced resource but just in controller directories.
So in routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :user
end
```

which means this:

```
admin_user_index GET    /admin/user(.:format)                  admin/user#index
                 POST   /admin/user(.:format)                  admin/user#create
  new_admin_user GET    /admin/user/new(.:format)              admin/user#new
 edit_admin_user GET    /admin/user/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/user#edit
      admin_user GET    /admin/user/:id(.:format)              admin/user#show
                 PUT    /admin/user/:id(.:format)              admin/user#update
                 DELETE /admin/user/:id(.:format)              admin/user#destroy
```

Everything works fine except the action "new" and this is weird since the _form render is the same in the "edit" action and that works fine. 
This is my controller within admin directory:

```
class Admin::UserController < ApplicationController
# GET /users
def index
  @users = User.all
end

# GET /users/1
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# GET /users/new
def new
  @user = User.new
end

# GET /users/1/edit
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /users
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end

# PUT /users/1
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to [:admin ,@user], notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
    end
  end
end

end
```

**And this is the first line of the form which cause the error: undefined method `admin_users_path'**

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
```

I can't figure out where the error is. Any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails conventions say that controllers should be pluralized. If you don't want to follow that convention, you can set the URL in the form_for tag with :url => `admin_user_path(@user)`. I highly recommend using the Rails conventions though, otherwise you'll constantly be battling with issues like this where you need to override the defaults.

You can easily update this code to use the Rails conventions by changing your controller class to `Admin::UsersController` and the route to `resources :users`

Comment: Ok it works. But why? I'm very new to Ror and I don't get why in the edit action it worked fine and in the new it didn't? 
Everything was just the same wasnt'it? Thank you by the way

Comment: It's sort of hard to explain in a comment, but basically Rails makes certain assumptions about how your URLs are built based on the REST concept. New objects are created by POSTing to the pluralized route and objects are edited by PUTing to the singular route. Since you only had a singular route, that's why edit worked. I highly recommend reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html since that explains routing much better than I can.